# Pygame Multiple bullets not spawning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, bullet

So im new at pygame and coding my first project- a side scrolling shooter. The issue im having is with my bullets: when i press the space key, some of the bullets will show up but there are times when nothing happens, and no bullets spawn when i jump. Not quite sure how to go about fixing this issue- any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Code is as follows:

```
import pygame
import math, random, sys, pygame.mixer
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 8192)
pygame.mixer.init()
jump = False
jump_offset = 0
jump_height = 250

k = pygame.key.get_pressed()

def events():
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

def do_jumping():
        global jump_height
        global jump
        global jump_offset
        if jump:
                jump_offset += 3

                if jump_offset >= jump_height:
                        jump = False
        elif jump_offset > 0 and jump == False:
                jump_offset -= 3

#Defining colours
BLACK = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)

#Window Settings
w = 1280
h = 720
half_w = w /2
half_h = h /2
AREA = w*h

#Initialising the window
pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h)) #Sets the size of the window
pygame.display.set_caption("Cattleman") #Sets the title of the window
Clock = pygame.time.Clock() #clockspeed for the game ie. 60fps
FPS = 600

#pygame.mouse.set_visible(True) #Allows the mouse to be shown in the game window.

background = pygame.image.load("background.png").convert()
backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight = background.get_rect().size

stageWidth = backgroundWidth*2 #sets the area which the player can move in
stagePosX = 0 #Records position of stage as the player moves

startScrollPosX = half_w

circleRadius = 25
circlePosX = circleRadius

playerPosX = circleRadius
playerPosY = 602
playerVelocityX = 0

playersprite = pygame.image.load("player_spriteR2.png").convert_alpha()
playersprite = pygame.transform.scale(playersprite, (130,130))

bullets = []

bulletSprite = pygame.image.load("Bullet1.png").convert_alpha()
bulletSprite = pygame.transform.scale(bulletSprite, (20,10))

#Sounds
#gunSounds = ["pew1.wav", "pew2.wav", "pew3.wav", "pew4.wav"]
#SOUNDS
shot = pygame.mixer.Sound("pew1.wav")
#------------------------MAIN PROGRAM LOOP------------------------#
while True:
    events()
    do_jumping()
    k = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if k[K_RIGHT]:
        playerVelocityX = 2 #Moves the player right
        playersprite = pygame.image.load("player_spriteR2.png").convert_alpha()
        playersprite = pygame.transform.scale(playersprite, (130,130))
    if k[K_LEFT]:
        playerVelocityX = -2 #Moves the player left
        playersprite = pygame.image.load("player_spriteL2.png").convert_alpha()
        playersprite = pygame.transform.scale(playersprite, (130,130))
    if k[K_UP] and jump == False and jump_offset == 0:
            jump = True
    if not k[K_RIGHT] and not k[K_LEFT]:
            playerVelocityX = 0 #If no input detected, the player does not move
    if k[K_SPACE]:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                bullets.append([circlePosX-100, playerPosY-20])
            shot.play()

    playerPosX += playerVelocityX
    if playerPosX > stageWidth - circleRadius-25: playerPosX = stageWidth - circleRadius-25 #Checks if the player trie to go past the right boundary
    if playerPosX < circleRadius+55:playerPosX = circleRadius+55 #Checks if the player tries to go past the left boundary
    if playerPosX < startScrollPosX: circlePosX = playerPosX
    elif playerPosX > stageWidth - startScrollPosX: circlePosX = playerPosX - stageWidth + w
    else:
        circlePosX = startScrollPosX
        stagePosX += -playerVelocityX

    for b in range(len(bullets)):
            bullets[b][0] -= 3

    for bullet in bullets[:]:
            if bullet[0] < 0:
                    bullets.remove(bullet)

    rel_x = stagePosX % backgroundWidth
    display.blit(background,(rel_x - backgroundWidth, 0))
    if rel_x < w:
            display.blit(background, (rel_x, 0))

    for bullet in bullets:
            display.blit(bulletSprite, pygame.Rect(bullet[0], bullet[1], 0, 0,))

    #pygame.draw.circle(display,WHITE, (int(circlePosX),playerPosY - jump_offset), circleRadius, 0)
    display.blit(playersprite, (int(circlePosX-80),playerPosY-100 - jump_offset))

    pygame.display.update()
    Clock.tick(FPS)
    display.fill(BLACK)
```

Comment: Some general pointers, don't do `pygame.image.load("player_spriteL2.png")` each loop. That's extremely taxing. Let alone do `convert_alpha()` and then `transform.scale()`. Do that stuff outside of the `while True` loop and juse use different variables for the two images. call them `sprite_left` and 'sprite_right` and swap `playersprite = sprite_left`.

Comment: Further more, `for event in pygame.event.get():` isn't doing what you think it's doing. Just skip that for loop and do `bullets.append([circlePosX-100, playerPosY-20])`.

Comment: Ive taken out the "for event" part but not im getting a continuous stream of bullets- how would i now implement a delay so that only one bullet is made every keypress?

Comment: `last_bullet = time.time()` and then do `if time.time() - last_bullet > 0.5: # spawn bullet'. That will spawn one every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Added the "last_bullet" code but now the bullets are not showing up. ive inserted that in the while true and then done the if statement for 0.5 as you suggested... Ideally it would spawn one bullet on keypress

Comment: I'm guessing you're doing `last_bullet = time.time()` every loop? Paste your current working copy of the code above here: http://gist.github.com (or some other paste service you like)

Comment: I have add a function in pygame library and that is working for me :

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MasterMP853/49f9e4b90489d3733525c508d3739496

Comment: pasted the link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this in my code that leaves multiple balls similar like bullets :

```
class Bullet():

def __init__(self, x, y):
    # self.image = pygame.image.load("SingleBullet.png")
    self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (25, 25))

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.centerx = x
    self.rect.centery = y

    self.is_alive = True

# --------------------

def update(self):
    self.rect.y -= 15

    if self.rect.y < 0:
        self.is_alive = False

# --------------------

def draw(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)
```

for getting keyboard :

```
 def event_handler(self, event):

    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            self.move_x = -5
        elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
            self.move_x = 5
        elif event.key == K_SPACE:
            if len(self.shots) < self.max_shots:
                self.shots.append(Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top))

    if event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key in (K_LEFT, K_RIGHT):
            self.move_x = 0
```

Comment: Inside my main class, I have a method that has fixed no of shots

Comment: how are you spawning these on a keypress?

Comment: Key event use :